# k-fold feature selection

Tags: r, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, large-data, boruta

I have a data set with 20 K variables. I have tried to select some features via `Boruta` and `FSelector` but I could not achieve because of lack of memory. I also tried to use `bigmemory` but I could not do it.

Now, I am thinking to divide my data set's columns to k-fold, e.g. 20-fold, then I will select features for each fold. After that, selected features for each fold will be combined and selection algorithm will be applied to them once more.

Is this a valid solution? Is there a chance to lost an important feature with above solution?

Answer (score 3):

I find the approach very interesting. In my opinion this procedure is correct, but I would repeat it several times randomly and choose those features more 'voted' during repetitions.

In addition, I propose a similar approach but doing the k-fold division not vertically but horizontally, i.e. considering all the features but only with smaller proportion of data. Probably both approaches lead to similar results, but it seems interesting to have both into consideration.

By the way, if you have problems with memory use something like: memory.limit(size=6000).

Comment: Thanks for memory advice but I am using Linux and there is no limit on memory.

Comment: Ok, then think on previous suggestions and let me know the results you obtain.